# How can I access ServletContext from inside of a BayeuxServer.SessionListener?

Tags: servlets, cometd

Is it possible to access the ServletContext from inside a BayeuxServer.SessionListener callback function? I have an object that I have been making available as an attribute of the ServletContext. I could just make it a singleton, but I was wondering.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the `ServletContext` directly, but you can access its attributes in this way:

```java
BayeuxServer bayeuxServer = ...;
BayeuxContext bayeuxContext = bayeuxServer.getContext();
Object attributeValue = bayeuxContext.getContextAttribute(attributeName);
```

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but how would I get the BayeuxServer?